# Connection String skipping the user id after _ in Web Host Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, deployment, connection-string

I have deployed my website to a web hosting that is running Plesk and ASP.NET Enterprise Manager. I have created a user `myapp_user2` and assigned it to `mydatabase_db1` but when I run my website, I can only see that error it skips the username after `underscore`

**Error:**

```
Cannot open database "mydatabase_db1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'W1\IWPD_271(myapp)'.

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="myappDBContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Areas.ADMIN.Models.Model.csdl|res://*/Areas.ADMIN.Models.Model.ssdl|res://*/Areas.ADMIN.Models.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\MSSQLSERVER2012;initial catalog=mydatabase_db1;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User ID=myapp_user2;Password='123345';App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove integrated security=True to use the user id in the connection string